# Web Api call method before action

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I want to set variable, what is common for all actions, in controller. This is the code:

```
        int id = User.Identity.GetUserId<int>();
        user = controllerContext.Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>().FindById(id);
```

So, I just want to call this code before each action. How can I do it? I tried to add it to

```
protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
{
}
```

but User is not filled in Initialize method yet. How can I do it?
Please, don't offer to create ActionFilter because I will not create unit test for this controller

Comment: If you want it before each action, then that's *exactly* what ActionFilters were designed for.   The comment about not wanting an action filter is unclear - you don't want to unit test the action filter? you're not going to unit test the controller?  Alternatively you can fall back to the .Net 1 global asax events, eg Application_BeginRequest https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470252.aspx#Overview

Answer (score 0):

User.Identity will be filled OnAuthorization. The process of controller-instantiating occures before authorization. So, the only way is to declare your controller property and set it OnAuthorization (for example via ActionFilter, such as you've wrote above). There is no way if you want User.Identity in the moment of controller-initializing, except rewriting the .NET MVC application request-handling pipeline...